# shouldSelectViewController not getting called

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, appdelegate

I am trying to call my shouldSelectViewController Delegate function. But it doesnt seem to work.

I did the following, but still the function doesnt get called

## .h

```
@interface myAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

## .m

```
@implementation TakeFiveCameraAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    tabBarController.delegate = (id)self;
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"test");
    return YES;
}

@end
```

I am not sure what am I missing here.

Comment: Have you connect the TabBar-Delegate in your xib/stroyboard-file?

Comment: @xapslock I tried, I get an error 'reason: `Changing the delegate of a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'`

Answer (score 0):

add in `viewDidLoad`

[self setDelegate:self];